# SQL query gets commented out in php when I use #temp to make temporary table - works fine with just temp

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

sql query is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_concat_tavel_info
AS
SELECT travelDate,empID,
         CONCAT(tripStart, ' >> ', tripEnd) AS trips_Code, 
         CONCAT(startAddress, ' >>  ', endAddress) AS trips 
  INTO #temp
  FROM te_tripDetails 
  ORDER BY travelDate;
  
  SELECT travelDate,empID,
  STUFF((SELECT N' ; ' + trips_Code FROM #temp WHERE travelDate = t.travelDate AND empID = t.empID FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]' , N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,N'') AS trips_Code,
  STUFF((SELECT N' ; ' + trips FROM #temp WHERE travelDate = t.travelDate AND empID = t.empID FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]' , N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,N'') AS trips 
  
  FROM #temp AS t
  WHERE empID = 6 AND travelDate = '2020-05-01'
  GROUP BY travelDate,empID
  ORDER BY travelDate;
```

I add it to my PHP/Codeiginiter code to call it as such and this happens:
[PHP Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG2ZQ.png)

It seems to not recognize #used here is not for commenting

HELP PLEASE !!!

Comment: Because a # denotes a comment in PHP https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php.  You'll need to escape it in some fashion.

Comment: @NathanChampion do you know how to escape it ?

Comment: Wrap it in single quotes and treat it like a string.

Comment: @NathanChampion tired that didnt work. Casts an error on  STUFF((SELECT N' ; ' + trips_Code FROM te_concat_trips WHERE travelDate = t.travelDate AND empID = t.empID FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]' , N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,N'') AS trips_Code,
         STUFF((SELECT N' ; ' + trips FROM te_concat_trips WHERE travelDate = t.travelDate AND empID = t.empID FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]' , N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,N'') AS trips

Comment: If this were Python you'd use triple quotes, `""" ...my query that spans multiple lines... """` but since this is PHP does `<<EOT ...my query that spans multiple lines... EOT;` work?